# Difference in build_depend in package format 3 vs. package format 2

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the [ROS 2 tutorial for writing a simple pub/sub package](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Tutorials/Writing-A-Simple-Cpp-Publisher-And-Subscriber/#add-dependencies), it says to add the following in the package.xml file:

```
<exec_depend>rclcpp</exec_depend>
<exec_depend>std_msgs</exec_depend>
```

But shouldn't these also have the `build_depend` tag? From my reading of [package format 3](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0149.html), it seems like they should also be build dependencies:

> build_depend: Declares a rosdep key or ROS package name that this package requires at build-time.

Aren't rclcpp and std_msgs required at build time?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/347516/difference-in-build_depend-in-package-format-3-vs.-package-format-2/) by [Jeffrey Kane Johnson](https://answers.ros.org/users/2517/jeffrey-kane-johnson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 452 on 2020-03-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) on 2020-03-25**:
Semantic of `build_depend` did not change between package format 2 and format 3.

You are right, the tutorial is incomplete, these dependencies are needed both at build-time and execution-time so the `package.xml` should list both `build_depend` and `exec_depend`, or simply `depend` if it also export headers with symbols for these packages.
An example a simple C++ publisher `package.xml` can be found [here](https://github.com/ros2/examples/blob/24dcb339e7f7041217c05e1eb7dca019238e495e/rclcpp/minimal_publisher/package.xml)

The tutorial can be edited via PR on github (there's an "edit on github" button at the top of the page)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-03-25**:
I don't believe anything has changed wrt `build_depend` (at least not in the context you are asking about).

This particular tutorial was added in [ros2/ros2_documentation#366](https://github.com/ros2/ros2_documentation/pull/366) and a comment about this was added ([here](https://github.com/ros2/ros2_documentation/pull/366/files#r339288128)).

Afaict, it should probably be `depend` instead of `exec_depend`.

**Comment by [Jeffrey Kane Johnson](https://answers.ros.org/users/2517/jeffrey-kane-johnson/) on 2020-03-25**:
Thanks, @marguedas and @gvdhoorn, that clarifies it for me. I also realize now that my interpretation of the documentation for package format 2 was not correct. I edited the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As suggested the comments, I submitted a PR to update the tutorial documentation: https://github.com/ros2/ros2_documentation/pull/574

---

Originally posted by [Jeffrey Kane Johnson](https://answers.ros.org/users/2517/jeffrey-kane-johnson/) with karma: 452 on 2020-03-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0